# how to receive json data in reverse order using jquery getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have used a php api to generate json data,

```
$db_result_set = $db->prepare('SELECT p.Id, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, p.Gender, p.Location, p.Email, p.Mobile,p.Message,b.BookTitle, b.BookGenre, b.BookWriter, b.BookDescription FROM personaldetails AS p LEFT JOIN bookdetails AS b ON b.UserId = p.Id ORDER BY p.Id DESC');;

$db_result_set->execute();

$final = [];
foreach ($db_result_set as $u) {

   if (!isset($final[$u["Id"]])) {
        $final[$u["Id"]]= [
            "Id" => $u["Id"],
            "FirstName" => $u["FirstName"],
            "MiddleName" => $u["MiddleName"],
            "LastName" => $u["LastName"],
            "Gender" => $u["Gender"],
            "Location" => $u["Location"],
            "Email" => $u["Email"],
            "Mobile" => $u["Mobile"],
            "Message" => $u["Message"],
         ];
    }
    $final[$u["Id"]]["books"][] = [
        "BookTitle" => $u["BookTitle"],
        "BookGenre" => $u["BookGenre"],
        "BookWriter" => $u["BookWriter"],
        "BookDescription" => $u["BookDescription"],
    ];

}   

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($final,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

output of this api is ;

```
{
"110": {
    "Id": "110",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"109": {
    "Id": "109",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"108": {
    "Id": "108",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"107": {
    "Id": "107",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"106": {
    "Id": "106",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"105": {
    "Id": "105",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
},
"104": {
    "Id": "104",
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "Gender": null,
    "Location": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Message": "",
    "books": [
        {
            "BookTitle": "",
            "BookGenre": "",
            "BookWriter": "",
            "BookDescription": ""
        }
    ]
```

I want to display the data in Decreasing format (i.e 110,109,108---) in html.

but when i fetching these json data in html using jquery getJSON function.
it is displaying in increasing format (i.e 104,105,106,106,---).

How to reverse the data i am getting in html using getJSON function.

jquery code in html;

```
function loadData(){
                    var url = "http://localhost/ReadExchange/api.php";
                    $.getJSON(url,function(json) {
                        console.log(json);

                    if(json) {
                        alert("Roger that"+JSON.stringify(json));
}



                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order probably changes, because a Javascript object has no order.

I would get rid of the keys in PHP, so that you just have an array in Javascript, which has the same order as in your PHP script:

Just use this before json_encode:

```
$final = array_values($final)
```

`array_values` just takes the array values and creates a new array with numeric keys from 0 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can call .get().reverse() on the returned data.

```
var sortedData = $(json).get().reverse();
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/9sfb5e6j/

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through it in a reverse manner :

```
var kS = Object.keys(testJSON);

for (var i=kS.length-1; i>=0 ; i--) {

     console.log(testJSON[kS[i]]);

}
```